# The device cannot run executables for arm64. - Xcode 8 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

If You are Working on Xcode beta and you got the error when you building your project as "The device cannot run executables for arm64." then follow this Solution:

-Select project and to go target build settings

- Enter the key "Build variants" to search box
- and just changed from "armv7" to "normal" or reverse it.

Comment: This is **question** or **Answer** ?

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, but you should separate the question and the answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah i was looking for answer section thanks

Comment: It's down there ⬇️

Answer (score 6):

**For Xcode Beta :**
Apple actually admits something very like this as a bug in Xcode 9.3 beta. The release notes for beta 2 say: "The first time you trust a device, you may receive a message that the device cannot run executables for the device’s architecture. (35319190) Workaround: The error message is erroneous. Disconnect and reconnect the device."